# Matlab - how display a waiting message or gif, when operation not done ?

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to show a loading message in Matlab, after start a treatment, and ideally disabled a button ? There is an example or a Linke? 
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There a loading bar in this matlab [example](http://www.mathworks.com/products/computer-vision/examples.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/vision/videostereo.html), each step have a waitBar.

It easier with an example to understand, but here the documentation : [waitBar](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/waitbar.html)

Comment: Here'a a better link for example `waitbar` usage than your first one: [Monitoring Progress of a Calculation](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2007/08/01/monitoring-progress-of-a-calculation/).

Comment: You're right. I just get a link of where I have see it :P I don't search for the best example. But your is better.

Answer (score 1):

[`waitbar`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/waitbar.html) can slow down your computation needlessly (by a lot if you're not careful). Though if you're doing GUI stuff already, it may have less of an effect – your question doesn't say. A while back, I wrote a full-featured, text-based `waitbar`-alternative for my own use that is much faster: [`waittext`](https://github.com/horchler/waittext). It produces a progress bar right in your command window. See the detailed help for all of the options. Additionally, there are many text and GUI `waitbar`-alternatives [on the MathWorks FileExchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/index?term=waitbar).

Again, if you already have a GUI, then a standard "disabled button" using callbacks is probably the way to go. Otherwise, you can try a combination of the standard `Ctrl-C` and the [`onCleanup`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/oncleanup.html) function. This won't give you exactly the same capabilities, but it will allow you to clear objects in memory, delete temporary files, close open files, etc.