# How to create a progress bar to monitor a simulation in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have a code in MATLAB and it take many iteration to terminates. To see the progress of my calculation so far I did a simple trick as follow:

```
for i=1:iter
    fprintf('Iteration #', i)
    %my code
end
```

Someone told me that display messages on screen to see progress make the calculation longer. I really need to see the progress, how can I do that with a faster way? I have heard that there is a `waitbar` function that I can use but I do not understand how to use it. I would like to get something like this using waitbar: "`(i/iter)*100 %` is calculated and `100-(i/iter)*100 %` is left".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matlab - how display a waiting message or gif, when operation not done ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20223378/matlab-how-display-a-waiting-message-or-gif-when-operation-not-done)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `waitbar`:

```
h = waitbar(0,'Please wait...');
for i=1:iter
    waitbar(i/iter)
    %my code
end
close(h)
```